# How to detect the title of Email on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, email, windows-mobile

I want to notify users when he receives a certain Email with a specific sound. So I need to detect the title of Email.

I can use MailMessage in framework 2.0, but this class is not supported in compact framework on Windows Mobile. Any suggestion about which class can I use? Or is it impossible?

Comment: The answer marked correct works well for me.
Here is a reference for how to use pop3 commands with C#--
http://www.bitscn.com/pdb/dotnet/200806/142694.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop3).

Use an ordinary socket-connection and connect to your user's mail-account (normally port 110). You can then execute some POP3-commands such as TOP which retrieves a part of the message. For instance:

**Example 1 - Return headers only:**

```
TOP 1 0
+OK Top of message follows
--- all message headers ---
```

**Example 2 - Return headers and first 10 lines of body:**

```
TOP 1 10
+OK Top of message follows
--- all message headers ---

--- first 10 lines of body ---
```

When you receive the same, you can parse the text for the word: "Subject:" which is part of the headers.

Here is a web-page covering some basic [POP3-commands](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/networking/pop3-commands/). In any case, by using Google you can find a lot of useful information about POP3.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept e-mails with  IMapiAdviseSink

http://blogs.msdn.com/hegenderfer/archive/2009/04/28/intercepting-mail-using-imapiadvisesink.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook namespace, but I believe that it doesn't allow you to read mail messages. Probably you would need to use [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415647.aspx). See this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2007/03/21/getting-started-with-mapi.aspx) for getting started. A lot of unmanaged code is involved.

Comment: Looks like PR_SUBJECT in Message Envelope Properties is what I'm searching for. Any guide on how to use that property?